# C external memory corruption detection and correction libraries?

Tags: c, ram, corruption, crc

I have an embedded system in hostile environment (radiation). The probability of a least one bit flip in 4 hours is 95% for the amount of RAM I have. How would I protect the data? Do I use CRC to detect errors then write fresh data into RAM using FLASH?